# Authentication variable in Web API header

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API.

This is my controller

```
public virtual IActionResult GetStatus([FromHeader][Required()] string authorization, [FromRoute][Required] string requestId)
{ }
```

Problem is the request header is not accepting a parameter with name authorization. If I change name to something else it works fine. But when I change name to authorization, it is not working. I added a middleware and see that the request header does not have authorization in header.

My organization specification wants the name to be authorization only so I can not have any other name here.

Is there any way a Web API endpoint can accept a parameter named "authorization".

I tried creating a custom `AuthenticationHandler`, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way a Web API endpoint can accept a parameter named
> "authorization"

**Reason: 1**

Well, your issue is pretty obvious. You may hear about `reserved keyword`. Like in `C#` there are some `compiler-reserve` key for example `static`, `class` `public` and so on. We cannot set variable name as reserve key word.

If you navigate to `System.Net.Http.Headers` namespace and then move to below details, you would see `Authorization` is a reserve key word for `HttpClient`b request and its not wise to manipulate that system reserve word at all.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
```

[image]

**Reason: 2**

Likewise, if you use  or attached `Swagger` in your `program.cs` so no longer you cannot use `authorization`, `Content-Type`, `Accept` as your self defined parameter, even if you use it will be skipped. However, Postman can allow you to do that. You can check [`swagger official reference here`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters).

You can see the example below:

**Swagger Request:**

[image]

**Postman Request:**

[image]

**Note:**

Apparently, you can ommit swagger then it might work. Nonetheless, if you are using `Authorization` and `Authentication` within your application, then you might face unexpected issues if you still stick to use `authorization` as your custom parameter.